# Regex for finding image references

Tags: javascript, regex, attr

1) `var chk = $(this).attr('src'); if (chk = "Images/1.png")`

2) `.attr('chk', 'Images/1.png');`

3) `if ($(this).attr('src') == 'Images/1.png')`

I can have above 3 syntax to set images in java script. Is there any Regex to get Images/1.png from above 3 syntax. If there is 3 regex for all above 3 syntaxes, It will be fine, but 1 Regex, if posible, will be great.

Comment: A regular expression to match what? Your code, or to examine the `src` of the image(s)?

Comment: BTW: That is jQuery not pure JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex to get all image references in .aspx, .js, .css, .cshtml, .html, .ascx is

```
"(?=\w)([\w\/]+(?:.png|.jpg|.jpeg|.gif))|([.\~\-\:\w\/]+(?:.png|.jpg|.jpeg‌​|.gif))"
```

Thanks a lot Aelor for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
[^\s\'\"]+\/[^\s\'\"]+
```

this will get you the desired result, it will find all the links (correct/incorrect format) in the sentence and give you .

Suppose you want only particular links with particular format

```
([^\s\'\"]+\/[^\s\'\"]+(?:png|jpg|jpeg))
```

this will give only those ending with png, jpg or jpeg

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/nL4vJ0

**update**

according to the comment of OP, I am posting a new regex which will be working in all his test cases.

```
(?=\w)([\w\/]+(?:\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg))
```

demo here  : http://regex101.com/r/wG5hX7

**final update**

```
(?=\w)([\w\/]+(?:\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif))|([\.\~\-\w\/]+(?:\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg‌​|\.gif))
```

final updated regex which supports all your conditions

Comment: Why is the Regex working only, if Image absolute path is in inverted comas. Suppose I have background:url(../Images/1.png), I should get ../Images/1.png, but the result is different. Is there anything to change in regex?

Comment: Sry, but I should get ../Images/1.png and not Images/1.png (if it has background:url(../Images/1.png)), I should get only the actual value inside the parenthesis.
I will be doing some operations further with this. I am actually changing its absolute path with CDN path, whereby i will change image reference to point to some static content site.
If then it has something like background:url(../../Images/1.png), I should get ../../Images/1.png.

Comment: will this Regex not cover @url.content("~/Images/1.png").
I am getting /Images/1.png and not ~/Images/1.png?

Aelor, I sincerely appreciate your efforts, but if you can give me just 1 Regex, where I can get all values inside the parenthesis, that would be great. I have also tried many regex, but cant get one.

Comment: If we have "<img id="12" src="images/reelGift12-big.jpg" alt="" onclick="getImageId(this);"></li>" we are getting only big.jpg?

I should get absolute path of image, whatever it may have, like hyphen or anything in image name.

Comment: you can update your answer as "(?=\w)([\w\/]+(?:\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif))|([\.\~\-\w\/]+(?:\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif))"

I am using this Regex and its working fine. This regex covers all, but image reference using <asp:image> tag.

Thanks a lot for your help and for your timely support. This was such a useful Regex.

Comment: How would i alter this to exclude the file name and extension from the result? I'm looking to replace variations of local image paths with a remote path